# Failed to make complete framebuffer object 8cd6 (iOS, programmatically created OpenGL view)

Tags: iphone, ios, opengl-es

I've been having a problem getting my programmatically created OpenGL view to work on certain iOS versions/devices. It seem to be most common on Jailbroken devices, but does also happen on normal devices. It appears to only be v4.1 or 4.2.1 that it fails on.

The device I have is jailbroken (it's not mine and certainly not my choice to jailbreak it!) and has v4.1 (8B117) of iOS on it.

The error is 8cd6, which means that it failed to attach the framebuffer (or something along those lines).

I've searched and searched, but none of the other solutions I've found have helped. Most of them are using a depth buffer too, but mine is purely 2D and has no depth buffer.

Here's how I create the buffers:

```
glGenFramebuffersOES(1, &defaultFramebuffer);
glBindFramebufferOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, defaultFramebuffer);

glGenRenderbuffersOES(1, &colorRenderbuffer);
glBindRenderbufferOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, colorRenderbuffer);

glFramebufferRenderbufferOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0_OES, GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, colorRenderbuffer);
```

Other setup values:

```
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
glOrthof(0, rect.size.width, 0, rect.size.height, -1, 1);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glViewport(0, 0, rect.size.width, rect.size.height);

glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_BLEND_SRC);
glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

int* mts = calloc(1, sizeof(int));
glGetIntegerv(GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE, mts);
```

resizeFromLayer:

```
-(BOOL) resizeFromLayer: (CAEAGLLayer*) _layer
{
    // Allocate color buffer backing based on the current layer size
    glBindRenderbufferOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, colorRenderbuffer);

    NSLog(@"Layer Bounds: %f x %f", _layer.bounds.size.width, _layer.bounds.size.height);
    NSLog(@"Layer Position: %f x %f", _layer.bounds.origin.x, _layer.bounds.origin.y);
    if(![context renderbufferStorage:GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES fromDrawable: _layer])
    {
        NSLog(@"renderBufferStorage failed!");
    }

    glGetRenderbufferParameterivOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, GL_RENDERBUFFER_WIDTH_OES, &backingWidth);
    glGetRenderbufferParameterivOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, GL_RENDERBUFFER_HEIGHT_OES, &backingHeight);
    NSLog(@"Backing: %d x %d", backingWidth, backingHeight);

    if (glCheckFramebufferStatusOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES) != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE_OES)
    {
        NSLog(@"Failed to make complete framebuffer object %x", glCheckFramebufferStatusOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES));
        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}
```

It's the line "Failed to make complete framebuffer object" that gets called with the error code 8cd6.

Comment: You might try adding some calls to `glGetError()` to see if everything before that call succeeds.

Comment: 8CD6 (`GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCLOMPLETE_ATTACHMENT`) doesn't mean it "failed to attach the framebuffer" (whatever you mean by that), but that one of its attachments (texture or renderbuffer bound to a color or depth attachment) is incomplete. So it seems it is the renderbuffer storage that is broken somehow.

Comment: Are you sure the correct FBO is bound when calling `glCheckFramebufferStatus`?

Comment: Ahah! I had (incorrectly) assumed that because backingWidth and backingHeight, etc. were getting set properly that everything else before it was OK. After putting in some `glGetError()` calls I'm getting 1280, `GL_INVALID_ENUM` after the `glBindRenderbufferOES()` in resizeFromLayer.

Comment: @ChristianRau I have very basic experience with OpenGL, on any level, so wasn't entirely sure what the error meant. But now I have a new error code to investigate, thanks to user1118321

Comment: @AnonymousReality Ok, that means `glBindRenderbufferOES` doesn't recognize `GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES`, given that a `glError` before this call returned `GL_NO_ERROR` so the error is really in that function and not a thousand function calls before `resizeFromLayer`.

Comment: OK, I have it sorted, thanks! I'll post my solution in a minute or two.

Comment: Have you run these statements in multiple thread?
If you did,then this error occurs.
put the codes in main thread.

Answer (score 5):

I have it sorted thanks to the two users above, who helped me realise something.

I moved the creation of the buffers out of the init function of the class and created two new functions:

```
-(void) destroyFrameBuffer
{
    // Tear down GL
    if (defaultFramebuffer)
    {
        glDeleteFramebuffersOES(1, &defaultFramebuffer);
        defaultFramebuffer = 0;
    }

    if (colorRenderbuffer)
    {
        glDeleteRenderbuffersOES(1, &colorRenderbuffer);
        colorRenderbuffer = 0;
    }
}

-(void) createFrameBuffer
{
    // Create default framebuffer object. The backing will be allocated for the current layer in -resizeFromLayer
    glGenFramebuffersOES(1, &defaultFramebuffer);
    glBindFramebufferOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, defaultFramebuffer);

    glGenRenderbuffersOES(1, &colorRenderbuffer);
    glBindRenderbufferOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, colorRenderbuffer);

    glFramebufferRenderbufferOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0_OES, GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, colorRenderbuffer);
}
```

I then added calls to these at the beginning of the resizeFromLayer function:

```
[self destroyFrameBuffer];
[self createFrameBuffer];
```

Comment: First, this is an update of your question and no answer. Second, you didn't say if this solved anything. In this case it might be an answer. But third, even then it would be a bad one, since you destroy and create a new FBO each time the window/whatever is resized. It would only be a workaround the real problem, which must be somewhere else.

Comment: "I have it sorted thanks to the two users above, who helped me realise something." - how is that me not saying it solved the problem? This method seems to be a fairly standard way of handling it on iOS.

Comment: Chistian in iOS you do destroy and re-create the frame buffer when the devide is re-oriented - which requires resizing it.  It's the standard way of doing it in iOS.

Answer (score 2):

I've just had the same problem on a project I'm working on

The error printed is:

> Failed to bind EAGLDrawable:  to GL_RENDERBUFFER 1
>
> Failed to make complete framebuffer object 8cd6

To fix this I had to make sure I **only mark the view for redraw while its self.window is not nil**.

I am using a `GLKView` with my own `CADisplayLink`

Comment: I had a similar problem, only the problem was that my GLKView had a zero size.  Self.window was non-nil, and if I held off rendering until the size was non-empty (maybe autosizing hadn't run yet), it worked fine.

Comment: @prewett - this was my issue too. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am using Cocos2d v2.x
I used the above solution to create my solution, that solved my simliar issue:

```
 -(void) destroyFrameBuffer
 {
   // Tear down GL
    if (_defaultFramebuffer)
    {
       glDeleteFramebuffers(1, &_defaultFramebuffer);
       _defaultFramebuffer = 0;
    }

    if (_colorRenderbuffer)
    {
       glDeleteRenderbuffers(1, &_colorRenderbuffer);
       _colorRenderbuffer = 0;
    }


 }

 -(void) createFrameBuffer
 {
    // Create default framebuffer object. The backing will be allocated for the current layer in -resizeFromLayer
    glGenFramebuffers(1, &_defaultFramebuffer);
    NSAssert( _defaultFramebuffer, @"Can't create default frame buffer");

    glGenRenderbuffers(1, &_colorRenderbuffer);
    NSAssert( _colorRenderbuffer, @"Can't create default render buffer");

    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, _defaultFramebuffer);
    glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, _colorRenderbuffer);
    glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_RENDERBUFFER, _colorRenderbuffer);

}

- (BOOL)resizeFromLayer:(CAEAGLLayer *)layer
{

    [self destroyFrameBuffer];
    [self createFrameBuffer];
    etc.....
```

Answer (score 0):

After spending a lot of time i found solution for this "Failed to make complete framebuffer object" i am using using masking on CCSprite, but before to initialize opengl methods that make masking possible i am adding sprite in a view, before adding you have to add a scheduler of 1 second and in that scheduler add your ccsprite in a view.

Cheers!