# OpenGL undefined cocos2d

Tags: opengl-es, cocos2d-iphone

Functions such as

```
glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
glDisableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
glColor4f(c2.r, c2.g, c2.b, c2.a);
glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, vertices);
```

give me an undefined error (use of undeclared identifier .. )

This is in Cocos2d 2.0, which should have the OpenGL es library linked to it.
I've got the code from this -> http://www.raywenderlich.com/3857/how-to-create-dynamic-textures-with-ccrendertexture
their sample code seems fine, I'm not sure what's different, I don't see any libraries to be missing from my declarations that they would have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Difference between Cocos2D 2.0 and Cocos2D 1.0 is OpenGLES version. Cocos2D 2.0 uses OpenGLES 2.0 and Cocos2D 1.0 uses OpenGLES 1.0.

Just avoid all immediate mode API. Here is one similar post: [Cocos2d 2.0 -OpenGL-Errors!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11662770/cocos2d-2-0-zillions-of-opengl-errors/11663486#11663486)