# OpenGL error in cocos2d

Tags: objective-c, xcode4, cocos2d-iphone, xcode4.2, box2d-iphone

```
glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glDisableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
_world->DrawDebugData();


// restore default GL states
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
```

// for drawing ploygons & sprites, i using above above code. but its not working properly

```
ERROR:
OpenGL error 0x0500 in -[CCSprite draw] 532
OpenGL error 0x0500 in DrawSolidPolygon 103
```

// What i do..?

Comment: Good to google before asking question in SO :p

Answer (score 0):

This error comes when you use OpenGL immediate mode calls in OpenGLES 2.0

Check out this: [Cocos2D 2.0 - Zillions of OpenGL errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11662770/cocos2d-2-0-zillions-of-opengl-errors/11663486#11663486)

Comment: In OpenGLES 2.0 Show, OpenGL error 0x0500 in -[CCSprite draw] 532, that error.